# Why git remote add is not working?

Tags: github

Why do I see an error message when typing `git remote add`?

```
$ git remote add origin remote repository https://github.com/hashanmalawana/Loginsystem.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Comment: There actually is *clearly* a question, a valid one at that, if one takes the time to look, instead of blindly downvoting or closing, and takes the effort to edit and investigate: one of the official GitHub help pages is confusing, and this question is a good opportunity to clarify it. That seems better that closing the question

Comment: @VonC - If one has to radically rewrite the post in order to extract/identify a question, then the downvotes are arguably justified.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth He is an undergraduate at Sabaragamuwa university of Sri Lanka and "very interested in I/T field and very enthusiastic about learning new things". Celebrate his participation to this site. Help him. Guide him. Mention https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Illustrate, by rewriting his question, how to ask better ones. He is worth it.

Comment: Thanks in advance @vonc
Appreciate you..

Comment: Thank you oliver..such a way to express about you via answering..you may be best in something.but don't forget sometimes there are somethings that your knowledge may be nill about it.anyways thank you for the responding to my question when i hadn't clear idea about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should type:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/hashanmalawana/Loginsystem.git
```

not

```
git remote add origin remote repository https://github.com/hashanmalawana/Loginsystem.git
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That way, you add a remote named `origin`, referencing the remote repo https://github.com/hashanmalawana/Loginsystem.git

And you won't see the usage message

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
```

---

I understand that the step 8 of "[Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)" can be confusing:

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
```

But the last three parameters are actually only one. It should read:

```
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
```

It is better to refer to the [actual man page for `git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html)

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```